# Why are they not equal outcomes?

Tags: probability

Flip two coins and note the number of heads. The outcomes {$0,1,2$} are equally likely.

Why is this statement False??
Isn't is all just $25$% chance of getting HH, HT, or TT?

Comment: You are correct, there is a 25% chance of getting HH, HT, or TT. You are forgetting the remaining 25% chance, of getting TH.

Comment: Since $3 \times 25\% \neq 100\%,$ even without any further thought we know the three outcomes and probabilities you gave cannot describe all possible outcomes.

Comment: $25%$ multiplied by 3 comes to $75%$, so there is an error (in this case, not counting HT and TH seperately)

Comment: To see more clearly why counting outcomes doesn't work with probabilities consider a wheel painted red with a small sliver of blue and we spin the wheel and consider the probability of getting a red or blue outcome. There are exactly two possible outcomes red and blue, but hitting the small sliver of blue is far less likely and no where near 50%.

Answer (score 3):

The sample space is ${HH}, {HT}, {TH}, {TT}$.

The probability of getting $0$ heads is $\frac{1}{4}$.

The probability of getting exactly $1$ heads is $\frac{2}{4}$.

The probability of getting $2$  heads is $\frac{1}{4}$.

These probability are not equal so the statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is that you have to differentiate between the physical coins. So HT and TH are distinct outcomes. This is true for many situations in probability: you must distinguish between each physical object.

So the probability of 1 head is 50%.